# Wget fails with certificate error

Tags: ssl, wget, ubuntu-16.04

As part of an automated build, we run download some code from github. Minimal example:

```
wget github.com
```

Recently, the command started failing with a certificate error:

```
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2017-10-05 11:43:45--  https://github.com/
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.

ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

I tried updating the certificate store, and wget itself:

```
update-ca-certificates
apt-get install wget
```

The error is still the same.
My wget version is GNU Wget 1.17.1, and the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to lie somewhere in packet configuration. Unfortunately, I am unable to tell exactly why. The suspicion is some `mono` version installed from a ppa was messing with our cert store.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar error on one of our websites that previously had HSTS policy enabled. The error persisted even after we disabled HSTS.

After some digging I found wget keeps HSTS info about a site in local cache file. Deleting the file resolves the problem.

```
rm ~/.wget-hsts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid checking the validity of the certificate adding the `--no-check-certificate` option on the wget command-line.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to make that part of the build process. Doesn't seem like a great idea security-wise.